# Scheduling management command with django_crontab package

Tags: django

Eventually the management command will be used to scrape data and populate a db once a week, but for now I am just trying to print on a scheduled basis. Here is the management command (located at `player/management/commands/update_data.py`):

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('This is working')
```

Now to the scheduling part...
I ran

```
python3 -m pip install django-crontab
```

Added the following to `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django_crontab',
'player',
]

CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * * ', 'django.core.management.update_data'),# I believe what I am saying here is run update_data every minute? 
]
```

and finally

```
python manage.py crontab add
```

which returned

```
adding cronjob: (1be0bb6367b686fd03a204d920284ed3) -> ('*/1 * * * * ',
'django.core.management.update_data')
```

I then waited a minute and "this is working" was never printed to the console. If anyone is familiar with this `django-crontab` (https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/) package or knows another way to schedule management commands, help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your system has a cron service? On a Windows system for example, this will not work since Windows has, at least not by default, a cron service.

Comment: Honestly, I just learned what cron was about an hour ago when I was googling how to schedule tasks with django... so I am not sure. Some tutorial I was following led me to this django-crontab package which appeared to be a simple solution. Seems I have more to learn about cron itself. I can add I am running mac os.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was posted a long time ago, but I had a very similar situation and couldn't find the solution anywhere on StackOverflow so I decided I'd post my solution here.

The thing that solved it for me on macOS Ventura 13.4 is to grant cron full disk access after doing all the previous steps you mentioned. To do so, go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access and add cron to the list.
Cron should be located in /usr/sbin/cron.

Also, my cronjob was a little bit different, as I used a different kind of syntax that is also mentioned in django-crontab documentation.(https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/)
Mine looked like this:

```
CRONJOBS = [
('*/1 * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['update_data'])]
```

Here, app_name/management/commands/update_data.py is the management command, just like in your project.

Hope this will help the next poor fella running into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my own **cron** job that periodically logs my IP address via a shell script. With Apple's **Migration Tool**, the task was propagated over 3 generations of Macs and remained functional. Only under **Ventura** it did not work anymore, although it is still listed under

`crontab -l`.

In addition to above I would like to mention that not only the **cron** service itself must have **Full Disk Access**, but very likely also the job that should be called. This is a bit strange as calling the shell job manualy works, but not when called from cron.

Since **cron** was deprecated by Apple somewhen in 2016 (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html), I changed my regular task to **launchd**. This is almost easier and runs a bit better because a message is displayed when the task changes, so you know better what is happening in the background. Still it is required to grant Full Disk Access to the periodically running job.

I found Orerez's answer just now when I wanted to post this as a question myself. (Both answers do not specifically refer to **django**, so may be some additional **tags** might help to find this answer.)